# How share my calendar to all user in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

After sync my outlook calendar with SharePoint Calendar, only myself can able to see. But I would like to show my calendar to all users in SharePoint. How to achieve this? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open your Calendar. Then at the top ribbon you will find **List settings** > **Permissions for this list** > then **Stop Inheriting Permissions**. Then you can add "`everyone`" with read permission. Then all user (aka `everyone`) can read your calendar.

Comment: Even after set appropriate permission, same issue exist. Any Suggestion?

Comment: What will other users see when browse your calendar URL?

Comment: All users only seeing my empty calendar but they should see all events in my calendar, any suggestion?

Comment: Then I am guessing the events are not stored in your calendar. The events maybe come from other calendar. By pointing to your event, you should get the URL like `https://<sitename>/Lists/List1/DispForm.aspx?ID=1`. That means your event is stored in List1. You should grant everyone `Read` permission to `List1`.